# VM for Linux on Azure. Open APS to pull user data

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, aps

We are planning on using our home built messaging service across our organization so we wanted to know if Microsoft allows VM for Linux on Azure and if it has open APS so we can pull data for users. Is It possible ??

Comment: This question might be more suited to stack exchange website and not stackoverflow.

Comment: @marcogmonteiro ... Duly noted. Will do it on the stack exchange website as well. Thank you for the reply.